# Publishing .Net Core application in Linux

Tags: .net, linux, .net-core, .net-core-publishsinglefile

I have a .Net Core 5 and i want to publish this application in Linux machine.

I installed .net core 5 sdk in this machine.

I used `dotnet publish AppName.sln` but i get the " restoring packages " message and it stops at this point.
I do not get the publish dirctory or the error messages to figure out what could be the cause of this problem.

am I missing requirements for running .net core application?

Comment: Out of interest did you try publishing with visual studio using the UI?

Comment: @AliK yes, i tried to publish it in windows and it works fine. But the problem is on linux only

Comment: When you say that "Windows works fine" and "the problem is on linux only", are you running the dotnet publish command on the linux system, or are you trying to publish a deployment *for* linux on Windows?

Comment: @Kevingy i tested the app on windows to see if it will create publish folder and check if the probelm could be from the app itself. My main goal is to publish .net apps on linux machines

Comment: @M.peace In case you missed it, see my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

@M.peace When I deploy to Linux, I publish the application on Windows and copy the files to (deploy to) the Linux system. I never *publish on* Linux. I only *deploy to* Linux. That's an important distinction. Here are portions of my deployment action plan:

On the Linux system: (For me, Debian. If you're not using Debian, this may vary.)

```
Install snapd
    (https://snapcraft.io/docs/installing-snap-on-debian)
    sudo apt-get install snapd
    sudo snap install core
Install .NET 5 Core SDK
    (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/install/linux-snap)
    sudo snap install dotnet-sdk --classic --channel=5.0
    sudo snap alias dotnet-sdk-50.dotnet dotnet
    sudo ln -s /snap/dotnet-sdk/current/dotnet /usr/local/bin/dotnet
```

Then, the Windows build machine:

```
Publish Application
    Target Runtime = linux-x64
    Deployment Mode = Framework-dependent
    Zip publish folder and copy to host
```

My publish settings are:

[image: Visual Studio .NET Core Web App Publish Settings]

That is all you need to do to get a built .NET Core project onto Linux. For there, you need to configure it to run. How to do that depends on whether the project is a web app or a console app. Console apps are relatively straight forward. Just run it using `dotnet project.dll`. Web apps require configuration of Apache and Kestrel.

Comment: I  have tried to publish in a different linux machine with  no network limitation and it worked. I think the problem cause by  publish which is trying to restore packages from the internet but due a private network, it's not working.. Thank you for your help :)